# Autocomplete jQuery muy lento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autocompletar

Tengo un input el cual estoy convirtiendo en un elemento autocompletable de jquery, cuando la pagina carga, llama a un `ajax` que carga los elementos en un `array` y despues los carga en la funcion de `autocomplete`:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ordenTrabajoReque" name="name" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
//SE CARGAR AUTOCOMPLETE DE ORDEN DE TRABAJO
    $.ajax({
        url: "getOrdenesReque",
        method: "GET",
        //data: { id: eventId },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (respuesta) {
            ordenGet = [];
            for (var m in respuesta) {
                ordenGet[m] = respuesta[m];
            }
            console.log("lista ordenes:", ordenGet); //Total:4293
        }
    });

    //CARGA EL AUTOCOMPLETE
    $('.ordenTrabajoReque').autocomplete({
        source: ordenGet

    });
```

El asunto es que cada vez que trato de realizar una busqueda en ese `input` dura demasiado o simplemente la pagina se cuelga, hasta que muestre una coincidencia, existe alguna forma de hacer mas agil la busqueda o en definitiva es por la cantidad de datos que tiene?

Comment: ¿Desde dónde se retorna los datos?, ¿una base de datos?

Comment: @OscarR correcto

Comment: Sin más datos, hay varios factores que pueden intervenir, latencia, capacidad del servidor, configuración... Puedes probar varias cosas **1.-** Basado en los resultados, dar respuesta a partir del 2º o 3º carácter **2.-** Limitar las peticiones cada X segundos **3.-** Cachear las respuestas por si se repiten no volver a llamar a la base de datos. **4.-** Cambiar la forma en como se gestiona el _autcomplete_ cachear la respuesta completa y que el script sea el que filtre la búsqueda. Esta última habría que comprobar si es más rápida que las consultas a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Cuántas veces solicitas al servidor datos de "getOrdenesReque"?¿Una sola vez o una por pulsación? Lo ideal es que solo solicites las órdenes una vez si estas no van a variar. Necesitaremos un ejemplo completo para determinar la causa de tu problema (si el ejemplo es mínimo pero funcional mucho mejor).

Comment: @OscarR Gracias por tu consejos, son 4000 datos que se guardan en el array  `ordenGet` lo malo es que todos empiezan con la palabra `GORE-xxxx` entonces al poner `G`me salen todos, lo unico que cambia son las `xxxx` que son numeros, lo que hice fue darle un minimo de coincidencia de 3 digitos, y siempre con el #, asi me filtra los que tengan esos numeros. No se cachear los datos, y solo llama una vez a la base de datos

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez cuando el documento carga el llama una solo vez esa funcion `ajax`  y despues la carga en el autocomplete (no se si el autocomplete cada vez que pulso algo el reevuelve a llamar los datos del array o una que cargue se quedan los datos ahi), pero contestando tu pregunta, solo una vez se llama el `ajax`